# Insert arrays into a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have 3 arrays:

```
id_ = [1,2,3,4]
names = ['Mark', 'Fred', 'Justin', 'Tim']
Jobs = ['Teacher', 'doctor', 'Coach', 'Fireman']
```

and I want to insert them in a dictionary using a `for` loop to have something like this:

```
 {1: ('Mark', 'Teacher'), 2: ('Fred', 'doctor'), 3: ('Justin', 'Coach'), 4: ('Tim', 'Fireman')}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will add a numbered (name, job) pair for each name:

```
dict = {}
i = 0 # or 1, if you prefer. but it's not proper to start a list from 1 when programming.
while i < len(names):
    dict[i] = (names[i], Jobs[i])
    i = i+1
```

as a for loop:

```
for i in id_:
    dict[i] = (names[i-1], Jobs[i-1])
```

but I prefer the first method as it doesn't require making a list of numbers first. This is also far more readable than the zip function. I had to do a -1 on each to make the count work, as he starts his numbering with 1.

Comment: That's not a `for` loop

Comment: No, because it's not the right way to do it. My method is better, since it doesn't require a list of numbers being premade.

Comment: @yes 1) The poster asked for a `for` loop; 2) A `for` loop doesn't require a list of numbers to be premade (e.g. `range(x)` is a generator)

Comment: @Woodford yeah but how in the world is that better. Not arguing further.

Answer (score 1):

If you zip together the lists, you can then iterate through them adding the `dict` entry with `i:(n, j)`.

```
id_ = [1,2,3,4]
names = ['Mark', 'Fred', 'Justin', 'Tim']
Jobs = ['Teacher', 'doctor', 'Coach', 'Fireman']

print({i : (n, j) for i, n, j in zip(id_, names, Jobs)})
```

Output:

```
{1: ('Mark', 'Teacher'), 2: ('Fred', 'doctor'), 3: ('Justin', 'Coach'), 4: ('Tim', 'Fireman')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> id_ = [1,2,3,4]
>>> names = ['Mark', 'Fred', 'Justin', 'Tim']
>>> Jobs = ['Teacher', 'doctor', 'Coach', 'Fireman']

>>> dict(zip(id_, zip(names, Jobs)))
{1: ('Mark', 'Teacher'), 2: ('Fred', 'doctor'), 3: ('Justin', 'Coach'), 4: ('Tim', 'Fireman')}
```

Documentation:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): Note that `zip` requires all of the lists to be the same length. If they are not, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).
- [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)